# Aws root user MFA - Entity does not exist

Tags: security, amazon-web-services

I am trying to setup MFA for my root aws user and I am presented with the following error message after I have selected Virtual MFA device

> Entity does not exist One of the entities that you specified for this
>   operation does not exist. The user with name Antonio cannot be found.

What exactly am I doing wrong? I am logged in with my root user.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to add MFA for the Antonio user instead of the root user.

Comment: @Tim Antonio is the root account
I have other users in IAM but Antonio, as far as I know, is the root user

Comment: You haven't given sufficient information to work out what's going wrong. Exactly what steps did you take? Are you doing this in IAM or somewhere else? Where are the screenshots? I think you're trying to do this in IAM, which isn't how you add root user MFA.

Comment: @Tim you are over complicating the issue. It's resolved now, so chill.

Comment: I simply asked for sufficient information to help you solve your problem. You're just lucky someone else had a similar thing at the same time, because you didn't provide enough information to really help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been having the same issue for about 30-40 min. Even got "Unexpected error" couple of times. However, everything seems to be working fine for me as i write this. Just created a new root account and managed to enable MFA on it.

edit:
I think there might be something more serious as i get "Bad Gaetway" error when trying to generate new Access Key.

Comment: Ok, so this might be a temporary thing. I will try later tonight or tomorrow morning.
Thanks

Comment: This was indeed the case. Some temporary issue. Tried today, the exact same steps and everything worked. Thanks!!